# Eclipse & Cocos2d-x: My First Project, I Changed The HelloWorldScene.cpp, but changes don't happen in the deployed game?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've just started developing for Android for the first time. I set up my Eclipse IDE following this tutorial, and building to a real device gets me the cocos2d logo and frame rates, with the title "Hello World".

However, as I try to experiment by changing

```
// create and initialize a label

auto label = LabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Arial", 24);
```

to

```
// create and initialize a label

auto label = LabelTTF::create("My Awesome Game!", "Arial", 24);
```

When running the game, these changes are not present...

In fact, i commented out the whole class, and it still built and run showing "Hello World"... By commenting out the whole class, I've selected all the text and hit "cmd+/" so that all the text within 'HelloWorldScene.cpp' is commented.

What am I doing wrong?

---

P.S.
I just noticed these red text errors in the console.... Don't know if they will help..

```
[2014-07-22 11:16:47 - KittyKatch] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.damesgames.kittykatch/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity }
[2014-07-22 11:16:47 - KittyKatch] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

---

and these...

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/Users/damianwilliams/Desktop/KittyKatch/cocos2d/cocos/math/kazmath). KittyKatch      pathentry   Path Entry Problem
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include).  KittyKatch      pathentry   Path Entry Problem
The value of the field Cocos2dxTextInputWraper.TAG is not used  Cocos2dxTextInputWraper.java    /libcocos2dx/src/org/cocos2dx/lib   line 40 Java Problem
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include).  KittyKatch      pathentry   Path Entry Problem
The import android.util.Log is never used   Cocos2dxAccelerometer.java  /libcocos2dx/src/org/cocos2dx/lib   line 32 Java Problem
Invalid project path: Include path not found (/sources/android/native_app_glue).    KittyKatch      pathentry   Path Entry Problem
Resource leak: 'inputStream' is never closed    Cocos2dxETCLoader.java  /libcocos2dx/src/org/cocos2dx/lib   line 56 Java Problem
The import android.os.Build is never used   Cocos2dxAccelerometer.java  /libcocos2dx/src/org/cocos2dx/lib   line 36 Java Problem
Invalid project path: Duplicate path entries found (/KittyKatch [Output path]), path: [/KittyKatch].    KittyKatch      pathentry   Path Entry Problem
The method dumpMotionEvent(MotionEvent) from the type Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView is never used locally   Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java  /libcocos2dx/src/org/cocos2dx/lib   line 354    Java Problem
```

Comment: Please expand on "commented out the whole class"; that should usually generate an error unless, of course, that class is used in that single line/block of code.

Comment: Thanks @ChiefTwoPencils. I have now updated the post to show what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project,

Then Click `Build Project`, to take effect changes.

Comment: Right click where exactly? I tried right clicking the project group inside with 'Project Explorer', but there is nothing called 'Build Project' there. So, folioing that I tried clicking Project/Build All from the top menu/tool bar. then tried again, still this did not update the actual deployment with said changes.

Answer (score 0):

Into **proj.android** you must execute a python script called **build_native.py**

> ./build_native.py